# Recursively access potentially nested value based on one or more provided keys

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, php-7.1, custom-function

I'm trying to access a nested array (an array which contains arrays which contains arrays …)

I need to get the last value, given the array and the path of keys.

Given foo and a…z i need to get

```
foo[a][b][c]…[x][y][z]
```

I'm wondering if there is any more elegant way than this?

```php
function getValueRecursive(array $array, string ...$identifyer){
    $value = $array;
    
    foreach($identifyer as $key){
        if(!key_exists($key, $value))
            return NULL;
        
        $value = $value[$key];
    }
    
    return $value;
}

$foo = [
    'a' => [
        'b' => [
            'c' => "Hallo Welt!"
        ]
    ]
];

echo getValueRecursive($foo, 'a', 'b', 'c');                                    // Returns "Hallo Welt!"
```

Answer (score 3):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/773154)

```
<?php

$foo = [
    'a' => [
        'b' => [
            'c' => "Hallo Welt!"
        ]
    ]
];
$result=array();
array_walk_recursive($foo, function($value,$key) use (&$result){
    $result[]=$value;
});
print_r($result[0]);
```

**Or**

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$foo = [
    'a' => [
        'b' => [
            'c' => "Hallo Welt!"
        ]
    ]
];
echo getValueOfArray($foo,"a","b","c");
function getValueOfArray($array)
{
    $args=func_get_args();
    unset($args[0]);
    $string="";
    foreach($args as $value)
    {
        $string.="['$value']";
    }
    eval('if(isset($array'.$string.'))
    {
        $result= $array'.$string.';
    }');
    return $result;
}
```

**Output:**
`Hallo Welt!`

Comment: previous one is much better and accurate. you can tell that user can do like that instead of what he is doing

Comment: To answer why this answer could have received dv's: 1. This answer includes absolutely no explanation and therefore makes no attempt to educate/empower the OP or future researchers. 2. The first snippet completely ignores the fact that the recursive function must receive arguments which dictate the key path to the desired value. 3. The second snippet is using `eval()` which is one of the most dangerous functions in the php language.  If any other technique can work without `eval()`, then use that instead. I am more shocked about the uv's that this answer received.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote [arrays library](https://github.com/Sevavietl/Arrays) that uses [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface to achieve such operations. It allows not only retrieve but also store and delete values.

For all `offset*()` methods I used higher order method `walkThroughOffsets`:

```
protected function walkThroughOffsets(
        &$array,
        Callable $baseCaseAction,
        Callable $offsetNotExistsAction
    ) {
        $offset = array_shift($this->offsets);
        if (is_scalar($offset) && isset($array[$offset])) {
            if (empty($this->offsets)) {
                return $baseCaseAction($array, $offset);
            }
            return $this->walkThroughOffsets(
                $array[$offset],
                $baseCaseAction,
                $offsetNotExistsAction
            );
        }
        return $offsetNotExistsAction($array, $offset);
    }
```

Having this method you can implement [`offsetGet`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php) method (that is called when you try to access array value) like this:

```
public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        $this->setOffsets($offset);
        return $this->walkThroughOffsets(
            $this->container,
            function ($array, $offset) {
                return $array[$offset];
            },
            $this->undefinedOffsetAction
        );
    }
```

Then you can get values as simple as with usual array:

```
$array = new CompositeKeyArray([
    'foo' => [
        'bar' => 'baz'
    ]
]);

var_dump($array[['foo', 'bar']]); // => string(3) "baz"
var_dump($array[['foo', 'quux']]); // => PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UndefinedOffsetException: Undefined offset quux.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is very similar to what I would recommend.  I suppose this is basically a "stacking" technique versus making conditional/repetitive calls of the custom function. I do find your approach to be sufficiently elegant.

Adjustments:

- Don't cast the incoming variadic argument as an array of strings -- just let the elements' datatypes as they are.
- The variadic variable contains a set of values representing keys -- so name the variable as such.
- The return value from this custom function call could possibly be any datatype (including `null`), so it is inappropriate to arbitrarily `return null` when an invalid key path is provided. Instead throw an exception so that a differentiation of outcomes can be made where ever the function is called from.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tKV4h)) ([Fringe Case](https://3v4l.org/ShPun))

```
function getValueRecursive(array $array, ...$keys) {
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (!key_exists($key, $array)) {
            throw new Exception('key path invalid');
        }
        $array = $array[$key];
    }
    return $array;
}

$foo = [
    'a' => [
        'b' => [
            'c' => "Hallo Welt!"
        ]
    ]
];

try {
    var_export(getValueRecursive($foo, 'a', 'b', 'c'));
    echo "\n---\n";
    var_export(getValueRecursive($foo, 'a', 'b'));
    echo "\n---\n";
    var_export(getValueRecursive($foo, 0, 'b', 'c'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ' .  $e->getMessage();
}
```

Output:

```
'Hallo Welt!'
---
array (
  'c' => 'Hallo Welt!',
)
---
Caught exception: key path invalid
```

Comment: @Verim there is no green tick on this page.  Have you had a chance to review my answer?  Please mark this page as resolved by accepting an answer.